# Copy element i in array to another array

Tags: c, arrays, char, strcpy

How can I copy a char to an array?

```
char s[100], p[100];
in = fopen("infix.in","r");

while (fscanf(in,"%s",s) != EOF) {
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(s); j++) {
        if (s[j] - 48 >= 0 && s[j] - 48 <= 9) {
            for (i = j; i < j + 1; i++) {
                strcpy(p[i],s[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

turbo c said "Cannot convert 'int' to 'char*' "

This is not working. How do I solve this?

Comment: Your code is very unreadable as it is now. Consider adding spaces where appropriate.

Comment: Please explain what your code is trying to do. It looks like it has something to do with finding decimal digits, but I am not sure what exactly is the intended behavior.

Comment: What exactly you are getting and what exactly are you hoping to get?

Comment: i want to do if s array is equals to number copy to another p array.

Comment: the edit is pending, needs more approve votes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but it seems you want to copy all digits from s to p. If that's the case, you need to know that strcpy takes pointers as parameters, not chars (so, as you wrote, it should have been `strcpy(p+i, s+j)`) and it copies the entire string, until the nul character (basically, all that is displayed by `printf(%s, s)`). To copy a character, just use the assignment operator: `p[i] = s[j]`.

Answer (score 0):

To copy one array element to another location, you can just assign it

```
p[i] = s[j];
```

Your loop goes from `j` to `j + 1`, copying just one element. This means, you can eliminate the inner `for` loop entirely

```
p[j] = s[j];
```

The test for a digit can be done with

```
if (isdigit(s[j]))
    p[j] = s[j];
```

You can also save the string length in a variable, to avoid the expensive computation. The entire loop becomes

```
int len = strlen(s);
for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    if (isdigit(s[j]))
        p[j] = s[j];
}

p[i] = 0;
```

But, it looks like you want to extract the digits, which would involve an additional index for the target array

```
int len = strlen(s);
int i = 0;
for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    if (isdigit(s[j])) {
        p[i] = s[j];
        ++i;
    }
}

p[i] = 0;
```

Comment: i just want if s[j]=digit copy that digit to p[i] not copy s array's entire element to P

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using strncpy which eliminates the need to loop and provides the required functionality out of the box.

strncpy(s,p,strlen(s);

Correction: the strcpy is unnecessary and should be replaced with an assign.

I also suggest replacing fscanf with fgets. There really is no need for fscanf here.

Comment: `p` is currently indeterminate, copying from it isn't a good idea. And strncpy doesn't null-terminate its buffer sometimes , so it is a poor choice for this operation.

Comment: My mistake, I was referencing the inner for loop but as others have pointed out it only needs to be a simple assign.